# Closing a pure html/css modal dialog causes a new history entry

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, browser-history

I am using

```
http://domain.com/page1.htm#modal
```

to open a modal dialog using css and the :target pseudo selector.

Problem comes when I close that using `<a href>close</a>`.  This closes the modal window correctly but also adds a new history entry.  So history now looks like:

```
http://domain.com/page1.htm
http://domain.com/page1.htm#modal
http://domain.com/page1.htm
```

Is there some way of preventing the action tag from creating this new history entry?

Comment: The easy solution is don't use an anchor, a Button with onclick might be better.  Or if the history is important, you can look into the history API.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: I was trying to find a way to solve this using html/css only so that the modal dialog still works even without javascript but that may be an impossible task.
@Keith: History API does lots of good things, I am using it in many places, but solving this issue does not seem to be one of them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the history API pushState / replaceState / popState practically allows you to do whatever you want with the history.  And yes, doing this CSS only I think is not possible, as that is the behaviour of an anchor tag.

Comment: History API does not, as far as I can see, allow you to delete history entries.

Comment: You just do history.back(), or history.go(-1), etc. your controlling the popState, so you can ignore it needed.  I'll add an example snippet..

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of messing with the history..
So as an example, when you close the dialog, you could just do history.go(-2);  to remove the last 2 history items.

```js
$('#removeHist').click(function () {
  history.back();
});

$('#pushdaft').click(function () {
  history.pushState({},'daft title', '?someparam');
  console.log('pushed location: ' + location.href);
});

window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  console.log('location now: ' + location.href);
}

console.log('hello');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#one">One</a>
<a href="#two">Two</a>
<button id="pushdaft">Add history</button>

<button id="removeHist">Remove History</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example Keith.  A bit difficult to read because of the use of the dreaded JQuery library but I can see how it works.  Final solution used in a seperate post below so I can include code.

Comment: JQuery not's too bad.. I do understand how some people see it as a big monster lib, as it becomes a big include, for when only a few function are required.  I just wish JQuery would go the lodash way, with NPM so that say you could do,   var ajax = require('jquery/ajax');

Comment: Having trouble with Internet Explorer so tested the above but it fails on IE:
Error: {
  "message": "SecurityError",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 23,
  "colno": 3
}

Answer (score 1):

For a CSS only pop up, you should use a checkbox or radio input instead of :target.
Then you will be opening the pop up with the pseudo class :checked, which doesn't create a history entry.

[Example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/Jovan-Ralic/pen/JjLjbev)

```
<body>
  <div class="pop-wrapp">
    <input type="checkbox" id="open" name="mobile-pop">
    <label for="open" class="open-pop">☰</label>
    <div class="popup">
      <label for="open" class="close-pop">×</label>
      <div>Text inside of the pop up</div>
    </div>
    <label for="open" class="close-pop-overlay"></label>
  </div>
</body>

<style>

*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 0.35s ease;
}
body {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#open {
    /* hiding the checkbox */
    display: none;
}
.popup {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100%;
    top: 10vw;
    background: white;
    padding: 5vw;
    z-index: 200;
    width: 80vw;
}
#open:checked ~ .popup {
left: 10vw;
}
/* An overly, to be able to click outside of the popup and close it */
#open:checked ~ .close-pop-overlay {
    position: fixed;  
    inset: 0;
    background: #00000040;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor: initial;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Using a checkbox or radio input instead of :target is an excellent, elegant solution to this problem. Simple. Just works. Avoids url hash and associated history issue. IMO this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution used, yes it does use Javascript but falls back to a mostly working senario if Javascript is not available:

```js
document.querySelector(".close").onclick = function() { history.back(); return false; };
```

```html
<a href title="Close" class="close"></a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work on Internet Explorer.  The history.back() does remove the #modal1 hash from the URL but does not update the screen to reflect this.  however, it works fine in Firefox!  Any suggestions how to force IE to update the screen and reinterpret the CSS without reloading the whole page?